# php mysql update multiple rows in different values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am doing update the table values of multiple rows.
So i using the query is

```
UPDATE `notification` SET `flag`='1' WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Where it is working as fine. But don't how to use it in php. My php code ishown below.

```
  $json = '[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]';
  $arr = json_decode($json);

if(is_array($arr)){
    $sql = "UPDATE `notification` SET `flag`='1' WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)";

    // I want to implement the code is here.
}
```

Here, 1234 is the id. The id is parsing from json. But how apply in mysql query. please help me?

Comment: did you execute that query? and which MySQL API is used to connect with?

Comment: I have success fully excecuted in mysql.

Comment: How to run a query with multiple values for IN clause is a duplicated question. While hoq to get your values from json is a different question, but nonetheless duplicated. use json_decode with second parameter and use array_column() to get values

Comment: how to check mysql api?

Comment: have to first convert all id in to csv form and after that you can able to run query directly